# Multiple Submit Actions

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, push-notification

I have a script given to me by another developer to send push messages to my Apps. 
I want to be able to send them from one page to both App types but cannot figure how.
Problem is I do not have any control over the pages on the server they are sent to.
If you look at the code the only differences in the two critical pieces of code are the Form action to send them to each Server page and the name of the App Id's...the other info remains the same.

I also found a piece of javascript to submit to two places from one button but could not get it working with both...

I know from reading that I probably need an array...Could someone please show me some code with these in an array with a submit button to send them to their respective pages.

Thanks in advance...

EDITED

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../ScriptLibrary/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<form name="push"  method="post" >
<input name="pushmessage" type="hidden" value="HAIR EXTENSIONS  ">

<p align="center">Notification Message:<br />
<textarea style="width: 280px; height: 150px; margin-bottom: 30px;     font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; border-color: #000; border-        width: 1px; resize: none;" name="pushmessage" id="push-message">    </textarea><br />

<input type='button' class="inputbtn" name='Submit' value='Push' onclick='sendFormData()' />
<form/>

<script type="text/javascript">
function sendFormData() {
  var formURL1 = 'http://apple/iPhone-message';
var formURL2 = 'http://google/android-message';
var postData1 =     {'publishersid':'appdeveloper','username':'myself','pass':'mypassword','appid':' CommunityApp-i','topics':'test'};
var postData2 =     {'publishersid':'appdeveloper','username':'myself','pass':'mypassword','ap    pid':'CommunityApp','topics':'test'};

 submitForm(formURL1, postData1);
 submitForm(formURL2, postData2);
};
function submitForm(formURL, postData) {
$('#push-message').append('sending data to url : '+formURL+'\n');
$.ajax(
    {
        url: formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data: postData,
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    $('#push-message').text('success');
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    $('#push-message').append('oops:error occured'+errorThrown+'\n');
        }
    });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use native submit button (that triggers a page change) but use a ajax submit method using XHR object.

You can take a look to this jquery plugin: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to html form tag, you can do that with this piece of this code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<form name="push"  method="post" >
<input name="pushmessage" type="hidden" value="HAIR EXTENSIONS  ">

<p align="center">Notification Message:<br />
<textarea style="width: 280px; height: 150px; margin-bottom: 30px;     font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; border-color: #000; border-        width: 1px; resize: none;" name="pushmessage" id="push-message">    </textarea><br />

<input type='button' class="inputbtn" name='Submit' value='Push' onclick='sendFormData()' />


<script type="text/javascript">
function sendFormData() {
  var formURL1 = 'http://apple/iPhone-message';
var formURL2 = 'http://google/android-message';
var postData1 =     {'publishersid':'appdeveloper','username':'myself','pass':'mypassword','appid':' CommunityApp-i','topics':'test'};
var postData2 =     {'publishersid':'appdeveloper','username':'myself','pass':'mypassword','ap    pid':'CommunityApp','topics':'test'};

 submitForm(formURL1, postData1);
 submitForm(formURL2, postData2);
};
function submitForm(formURL, postData) {
$('#push-message').append('sending data to url : '+formURL+'\n');
$.ajax(
    {
        url: formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data: postData,
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    $('#push-message').text('success');
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    $('#push-message').append('oops:error occured'+errorThrown+'\n');
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks very much lads for very quick replies. I will take a look at that method Tarani. Regarding your code Ebrahim...which is very detailed and I really appreciate your trouble to type that out....because both pages need the App id whcih is different for the iPhone and Android...lets call them iphoneapp and androidapp...how or where could I incorporate those into your code to avoid an error??

Comment: hey meself, (sorry for my bad english :) ), i you have extra code that not exist in you forms you can put in postdata like this . `postdata1.code='123'` and for your second use `postdata2.code='456'` and then send postdata1 and postdata2 to submitform

Comment: Thank you Ebrahim...your english is good,,,that did not work for me....when I wrap your code in a <script type...> etc...it throws a syntax error..on this line function SubmitForm(formUrl, postData) {
    $.ajax(...when I click submit it does nothing

Comment: thanks very much for that. I have edited my original code too to show you....I also have added a Topics data to taget Topics in my Apps..when I click the button it does nothing.....does not move...no error...what have I missed??

Comment: i think that because you didn't use jquery. i updated my code. test this code

Comment: Thanks for that but it did not work either....on press the page does nothing...I posted all of my page code....I appreciate your time Ebrahim...

Comment: really sorry for wasting your time Ebrahim....that does not work either. The button does nothing when I press it....really maddening ...

Comment: Hello....thanks to Ebrahim for his previous attempts at a soluton for me but I still cannot get this working? Would anyone have any idea how to solve this??